# Responsive DIVs 50% Max Width

Tags: html, css

I don't believe I am coding this correctly. Trying to have two DIVs next to each other inside a parent DIV that act responsively. Both should be 50% of the screen, however I need about a 10px margin between them. Does the way I'm coding this so far make sense?

```css
.box-container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 84px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color:#ED3538;
 display:flex;
}

.box50-1, .box50-2 {
 padding: 15px;
    background-color:#353535;
    background: rgb(53, 53, 53); /* older browsers */
    background: rgba(53, 53, 53, 0.7);
 float: left;
 width: 45%;
}

.box50-1 {
 margin-right:5px;
}

.box50-2 {
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">

 <div class="box50-1">
  <h3>This is a title 1</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>
 </div>

 <div class="box50-2">
  <h3>This is a tille 2</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, it's not, but you're not asking a specific question. Read [ask] and fix your post

Comment: So a rule follower because I don't phrase my question correctly. Okay thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it https://jsfiddle.net/quod8jfL/1/

use `calc(50% - 5px)` so both div's are exactly the same width and will always leave a 10px gap for the margin between the two.

```
 .box-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 84px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#ED3538;
    display:flex;
}

.box50-1, .box50-2 {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color:#353535;
    background: rgb(53, 53, 53); /* older browsers */
    background: rgba(53, 53, 53, 0.7);
    float: left;
    width: calc(50% - 5px);
}

.box50-1 {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```